# Getting context of other applications (processes) in my app: Android

Tags: android, eclipse

In my application I need to access context of other installed apps.
Is it possible to get context using package name of any app?

And if I'm accessing context of other apps will it be any security issue?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Short answer, no.  Applications are sandboxed.  Each one runs in it's own VM with a unique user ID.  And a good thing too.  Imagine the security nightmare if an app could access another apps context.  Android would have died a long time ago.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "I need to access context of other installed apps"?Which access you exactly need?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Then is it possible to create context of other apps in my own app?

Answer (score 6):

try [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#createPackageContext(java.lang.String,%20int))

```
public abstract Context createPackageContext (String packageName, int flags)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit old and will not give access to other app context but this is how you pass data between applications:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html